# Make table behave as a block element while aligned to right

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table (aligned to the right) and more html elements appear underneath it. In other words, I would like it to behave as if it's a block element.

But the paragraph after the table in the div displays to the left of the table, and I want it to appear underneath the table. Please check my jsfiddle to see:
https://jsfiddle.net/wLysjc6v/

```html
<div>
  <table align="right">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ab</td>
        <td>ab</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bb</td>
        <td>bb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cc</td>
        <td>cc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p> why am i here?</p>
```

Comment: remove align="right" and it's done

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to mention that I do want it to align to the right. I will update my question

Comment: Oh you're right after removing the align="right" I can change the display to block. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure if I should remove this question

Comment: or you can style `p` `style="clear: right"`, check my answer

Comment: don't make it block, keep it table and add margin-left:auto

Comment: The align attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Thanks guys and thanks Temani if you can change it into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your `<table align="right">` has `float: right` on it, this takes it out of the normal flow of the page (the same as how using `position: absolute` does).

Remove the align and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <table align="right">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ab</td>
                <td>ab</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>bb</td>
                <td>bb</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cc</td>
                <td>cc</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>

<p style="clear: right">
why am i here?
</p>
```